# Memory adress of function in C language

Tags: c, arm, memory-address

I am working on sleep mode with ARM Cortex M3 processor. I have to fill some structure for this.

Here one of them

```
struct sleep_mode_init_env_tag
{
    /* Wake up configuration */
    uint32_t wakeup_cfg;

    /* Wake up restore address */
    uint32_t wakeup_addr;

    /* Wake up application start address */
    uint32_t app_addr;

    /* Memory power configuration for wake-up */
    uint32_t mem_power_cfg_wakeup;

    /* Clock source for RTC */
    uint8_t rtc_ctrl;

    /* DMA channel used to save/restore RF registers
     * in each sleep/wake-up cycle */
    uint8_t DMA_channel_RF;
};
```

When ı goes to sleep mode in main loop, ı want to return main loop again after 1 minute. So you can as see as ı have to write memory address of wake up function here ;

```
uint32_t app_addr;
```

And there  is my return function;

```
void Turn_Wake_up(void) {

    Sys_PowerModes_Wakeup();

    Sys_Watchdog_Refresh();

    Device_Config();
    
    memory_access();

    main_loop();

}
```

Manufacturer company created this .S file (wake_up.S) and included to project for memory address of wake up function ;

```
  .thumb_func

    .section .app_wakeup_asm
    .globl Turn_Wake_up_asm
    .extern __stack, 4

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Function      : void Turn_Wake_up_asm()
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Description   : Initialize stack pointer and continue execution
 * Inputs        : None
 * Outputs       : None
 * Assumptions   : None
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
Turn_Wake_up_asm:
    movw r0, #:lower16:__stack
    movt r0, #:upper16:__stack
    msr msp, r0

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * File end
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    .end
```

and they have did this;

```
(uint32_t) (&Turn_Wake_up_asm)
```

So, I have simply used this;

```
(uint32_t) (&Turn_Wake_up);
```

and ı haven't got any error but it didn't work.So my main question is ;

"What is different between (uint32_t) (&Turn_Wake_up); and (uint32_t) (&Turn_Wake_up_asm) ?"

Note that:

*** I have not any information about content of .S file...

Thank you...

Comment: There one line in the comment header for the `Turn_Wake_up_asm` function that could be seen as crucial: "Initialize stack pointer and continue execution". Before the stack is properly set-up you can't call any other functions.

Comment: I think you are confusing an embedded application with a function. The former does much more low level initialisation and usually is jumped to, in contrast to called.

Comment: So, Do you mean ı can return memory address of wake up function with this line ; (uint32_t) (&Turn_Wake_up) ?@Someprogrammerdude

Comment: If your function does the things needed for the system to get going again (which should be in the documentation, I hope) then you can use your own custom function if you want.

Comment: I dont see how the two functions are remotely related to each other other than they have similar label names.  Completely incompatible functions.   Read the arm documentation and the chip documentation, its not for us to do that for you.

Comment: Documentation is not enougly for me.But ı think there is a essentiality there about using .S file... @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: If you disassemble the function, you'll see there's a function entry and exit. `Turn_Wake_up_asm` is not actually a function (or, well, you might say it's a naked function), and it appears it does some crucial setup as mentioned in other comments. You will most likely need a bit of assembly (either .S file, or inline assembly) to handle return from sleep.